# where can i get exactly mdi icons to use vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I was struggling to find where I can find easily material design icons to use in #vuetify,

where you can do like `<v-icon>mid-iconname </v-icon>`

Answer (score 4):

here is the link that helped me,[mdi-iconname](https://pictogrammers.github.io/@mdi/font/1.1.34/)